# Increasing neo4j performance when doing large number of writes

Tags: performance, neo4j, database-performance

I am trying to load data into neo4j through my application. This is using bolt driver. My application is initially very write intensive. I am unable to reduce the load time as neo4j writes seem to be pretty slow with bolt driver. I see all threads doing below operation:

```
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(java.io.FileDescriptor, long, int)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(java.io.FileDescriptor, long, int)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.nio.ByteBuffer, long, sun.nio.ch.NativeDispatcher)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.nio.ByteBuffer, long, sun.nio.ch.NativeDispatcher)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(java.nio.ByteBuffer)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.channelRead(java.nio.ByteBuffer) (line: 159)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.unwrap(java.nio.ByteBuffer) (line: 229)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.read(java.nio.ByteBuffer) (line: 419)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.readNextPacket(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel, java.nio.ByteBuffer) (line: 409)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.readChunkSize() (line: 345)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.read(java.nio.ByteBuffer) (line: 247)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.fillScratchBuffer(int) (line: 216)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.readByte() (line: 110)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.packstream.PackStream$Unpacker.unpackStructHeader() (line: 430)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.MessageHandler) (line: 398)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler) (line: 176)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.receiveOne() (line: 212)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.receiveOne() (line: 165)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledSocketConnection.receiveOne() (line: 183)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.receiveOne() (line: 335)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.tryFetchNext() (line: 325)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.hasNext() (line: 193)
```

- Heap Memory min and max =4Gb
- Page Cache size = 2 GB
- Total database size approx = 2 GB (Expected to grow up to 10GB)

Is there a way i can optimize for the above operation? I can increase the heap up to 8 GB as other applications are running on this machine as well.

Comment: You'll need to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e application is write-Intensive, you'll benefit from performing your writes with batched transactions ( do this from your application -> aggregate the nodes \ edges until you reach this side , open a transaction , and commit when reaching this size). you can play with the batch size ( 1000, 10000) and see what is working best for you.